# Add support for next-css and next-less simultaneously in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am using nextJs and need to add support for both less and css. I want to have next-css and next-less both for a project. But It accept one at a time. Here is what I am using

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  /* config options here */
})

const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
module.exports = withLess({
    cssModules: false,
    lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true
    }
})
```

Am I including both loaders correctly? And I need javascriptEnabled: true too. How can we acchieve this configuration.

I really appreciate if you can give any hint or two.

Comment: Why do you need `next-css`?

Comment: Are you right. I was converting create react app to nextjs app. So for this will convert my css files to less. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
module.exports = withCSS(withLess())
```